# Get amount of serialized objects in stream to randomly choose one

Tags: c#, serialization, stream, binaryformatter

I'm trying to get the amount of serialized objects in the stream I'm serializing and deserializing from. I want to do this to create a random value between 1 and that amount.

Is this possible to do and how?

Currently my code is:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
Stream stream = new FileStream("File.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
int randomNumber = rnd.Next(1, (int)stream.Length);
```

However, this won't work since `stream.Length` value is over 1000, whilst there are about 3 serialized objects in the file.

I'm using `BinaryFormatter` to do the serialization.

EDIT: I should add that the objects serialized to the file are multidimensional arrays (int[,]), and they have a number stored with them. The first object has number 1, second has 2, etc.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The size of the serialized objects is probably variable so it's not possible to determine how many there are without deserializing them all, unless you write that information somewhere when they are first serialized. But if the objects are fixed size (don't have strings, for example) then you could work it out if you know the serialized size of them in advance - then you can divide the file length by the serialized size per object.

Comment: And how could I be able to do that? It's a very good idea but I'm not sure how to do it. I was thinking of increasing a value by 1 each time an object is serialized, but the value is supposed to remain when the application/project is closed and opened again later on.
Edit: the objects are not fixed size.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately if the objects are not fixed size then you will have to deserialize them all and randomly choose one.

Comment: Is there no way to get a certain value from the file? All the objects are multidimensional arrays (int[,]) and are stored with a specific number.Could it be possible to count how many times a int[,] occurs in the stream or that specific number?

Comment: If you do know that information then you should be able to do it, in theory. As long as the format doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You can select an item at random from a list of unknown size, but you'll have to scan the entire list in order to do it. You do not, however, have to keep all the items in memory in order to select one.

See my article [Random Selection from Large Groups](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=796), especially the heading "What if I don't know how many there are."